# Why does my PHP include statement fail when I include the directory in the relative path?

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax

I'm fairly new to PHP, and am still learning how some of the include/require functions work. I'm working on a plugin, and I'm trying to break up the main template into a few files to make it easier to read/maintain (if this is a bad idea, that's a whole other discussion). My plugin public folder looks kind of like this:

```
resources-plugin
    ├── includes
    │   ├── class-resources-short-codes.php
    │   └── index.php
    ├── index.php
    ├── public
    │   └── partials
    │       ├── resources-banner.php
    │       ├── resources-filters.php
    │       ├── resources-items.php
    │       └── resources-query.php
```

In my **class-resources-short-codes.php** file, I have three working include statements:

```
add_shortcode( 'example-resources-sc', function () {

    // Banner
    include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . "/../public/partials/resources-banner.php" );

    echo "<article class='resources flex-container'>";

    // Filters
    include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . "/../public/partials/resources-filters.php" );

    // Resources
    include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . "/../public/partials/resources-items.php" );

    echo "</article><!-- /resources -->";

} );
```

Then, in the child template **resources-filters.php**, I have another include that is supposed to pull in the HTML from the **resources-query.php** file:

```
<?php

// Doesn't work
// include( "./resources-query.php" );
// include( plugins_url("resources-plugin/public/partials/resources-query.php") );

// Works
//include( "resources-query.php");
include( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . "/resources-query.php";

?>

<div class="slide-container">Other HTML here.</div>
```

My question is - why do two of these methods work, but the other two don't? I know I'm a little confused on how file paths are determined when you're using nested include statements.

PHP version: 5.3.3
Wordpress version: 4.2.2

Thanks!

Comment: Starting a path with `/` means start at the root.

Comment: I don't know how the last example could be working.  Parentheses are wrong. Change:

    `include( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . "/resources-query.php";`

to:

    `include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . "/resources-query.php");`

Comment: @manassehkatz This is definitely a typo in my code as well, so I have NO idea why it works, but it's displaying.

Comment: @manassehkatz I made the fix and it still works, so I have no idea. Thanks for the catch though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing first I'd recommend only using dirname() once at the top of your script if you need to. If you look in wp-config.php you'll see that they do something similar around line 80 like this:

```
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

in your case you could do something like this:

```
define('MYPATH', dirname(__FILE__));


add_shortcode( 'example-resources-sc', function () {

    // Banner
    include( MYPATH . "/../public/partials/resources-banner.php" );

    echo "<article class='resources flex-container'>";

    // Filters
    include( MYPATH . "/../public/partials/resources-filters.php" );

    // Resources
    include( MYPATH . "/../public/partials/resources-items.php" );

    echo "</article><!-- /resources -->";

} );
```

Now to the questions you asked:

```
include( "./resources-query.php" );
```

This does not work because by default PHP won't assume the directory you are in. Strangely PHP will allow you to reference a file in the same directory if you remove the `./` but try to avoid this behaviour as it is just confusing in general.

```
include( plugins_url("resources-plugin/public/partials/resources-query.php") );
```

The problem with the second example you gave is that you are trying to include a URL not a path. Some systems allow this, but by default most do not.

As a rule I would recommend always including files using absolute file names like you did in the examples that work. Maybe consider defining a constant like I mentioned and this should help make sure you are always pointing to the right paths. If you need some error feedback to explain things consider using `require_once` instead of `include` for testing purposes. And finally consider staying away from using paths that contain /../ as they will just give you headaches in the end.

Koda

Comment: This worked and made a lot of sense."This does not work because by default PHP won't assume the directory you are in." I didn't know that either. Thank you!